# More slashes when using mysql_real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysql-real-escape-string

I'm a little confused with `mysql_real_escape_string()` function,

I have this array below and filtering it with `mysql_real_escape_string()` function,

```
$postFields = array('company', 'type');
$postArray = array();
foreach($postFields as $postVal){
    $_POST[$postVal] = array_map("mysql_real_escape_string", $_POST[$postVal]);
    $postArray[$postVal] = $_POST[$postVal];
}
```

so the results is like this,

```
Array
(
    [type] => Array
        (
            [0] => CD
        )

    [code] => Array
        (
            [0] => \\\'\\\' OR \\\'\\\'
        )
)
```

but when I want to use it single like this,

```
echo mysql_real_escape_string($postArray['company'][0]);
```

I'm getting more slashes, like this,

```
\\\\\\\'\\\\\\\' OR \\\\\\\'\\\\\\\'
```

Any reason for it, or I just do something wrong.

Comment: First, don't use `mysql_*` functions. They are about to be deprecated. Use PDO or `mysqli` instead.

Comment: No problem, I know about it, but first I need to fix that one.

Comment: depreciation only matters if your selling software or giving it away to the masses, or are intent on upgrading sooner than later. If you keep the same server you'll be fine. Not to say upgrading is a bad thing, or shouldn't be done. But overall.. it is what it is.

Comment: `stripslashes()` may help remove the extras but thats negating what real_escape is there for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code you provide, you're escaping the string twice:

```
$postFields = array('company', 'type');
$postArray = array();
foreach($postFields as $postVal){
    $_POST[$postVal] = array_map("mysql_real_escape_string", $_POST[$postVal]);
    $postArray[$postVal] = $_POST[$postVal];
}
echo mysql_real_escape_string($postArray['company'][0]);
```

Each time you escape the string, all of the backslashes get escaped into two backslashes.  Be careful to only escape each string once.